# Workflow to edit fields on converted leads

Tags: process-builder, lead-conversion, leadmapping, source

I'd like to create a workflow (ideally in Process Builder) that changes LeadSource on the Lead record after it has been converted when AccountSource is changed on the Account.

Context: inbound leads are automatically created in SFDC when a customer registers on our site. Due to reps not manually entering leads before the customer takes action, reps convert these "Inbound" leads and do not always adjust the lead source before they convert it (i.e. change to "Outbound" as the source). These are easy to catch later on in the sales cycle, but it results in discrepancies between the LeadSource on the Lead object and the later corrected AccountSource on the Account. Our Data Science team uses these converted lead records to look at total lead volume and performance by lead source, and this results in regular QAing and manually changing the lead source on the converted lead record (which is a pain in many ways).

Is there a way to automatically change LeadSource on the converted Lead object when the AccountSource is corrected?

Any insight is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is how to update a child record of a parent when the parent record changes, [here'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340214&type=1&mode=1)s one article which instructs how to do it step by step using the process builder.

> 1. Create a new [Process](http://articleView?%20id=process_example.htm&type=5&language=en_US)
> 2. Select the Record  you would   like to update
> 3. Define the criteria
> 4. In 'Immediate Action', select Update Records
> 5. Click the 'Object' Picklist, then select the Account record that started your process and  select a record related to the Account:
>      **Note**: These records are radio buttons, and    only one may be selected. To update child   records, select the send    option 'Select a
>      record    related to the Account'
> 6. In 'Find   a field', look for the child    Object name you want to update: Note: If the child  Object is a Custom Object, the name
>      would end with '__r'
> 7. Select the child Object name, then click Save
> 8. In 'Set new value', select the field   that you want to update in child records and    what value the field should contain
> 9. Click Save

To make sure that you are updating only converted leads, use the IsConverted field on Lead.